# Enabling variable length input padding while batching in TFServing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

The following proto definition has the details of a flag (pad_variable_length_inputs) which can be enabled to pad requests.

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/1f8f2902b6465f239bb58af2b3fb27ba73b5c7c5/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/session_bundle_config.proto

My current batching config file looks like this :

```
max_batch_size { value: 300 }
batch_timeout_micros { value: 0 }
max_enqueued_batches { value: 1000000 }
num_batch_threads { value: 8 }
```

I am wondering how can I set the pad_variable_length_inputs through the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. This is how it can be done :

```
max_batch_size { value: 300 }
batch_timeout_micros { value: 0 }
max_enqueued_batches { value: 1000000 }
num_batch_threads { value: 8 }
pad_variable_length_inputs: true
```

Comment: Hi, i have been able to use pad_variable_length_inputs to batching my data, however,do you kow what is the default value that the tensorflow serving padded to the data?

Comment: AFA I remember TFServe uses the first vector of the batch to get the padding value.

Comment: that means we cannot config to make sure it uses which value to pad? because I hope I can use the pad value that I used in training.@@

Comment: No. I don't think so.